# Pass different argument names to a function depending on condition

Tags: python, function, variables, lambda

My code needs a way to determine which one of two argument *names* (not values) it should pass to an API function. There are two possible variable names, and only one of them will be used in the call. Something like this metacode:

```
user_input = 'tgw-xxxx'

if user_input == 'tgw-xxxx':
    <gateway = (TransitGateway=user_input)>
else:
    <gateway = (VpnGateway=user_input)>

some_api_call(
   CustomerGatewayId='blah',
   BgpAsn=65000,
   <gateway>      # pass either `TransitGateway` argument
                  # or `VpnGateway` argument
  )
```

So in other words the API will *only* accept either the TransitGateway or VpnGateway variable here, but not both.

Do you know the best way to address this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Python docs for [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) to functions. Basically, you'll want to create a dictionary to hold your values:

```
user_input = 'tgw-xxxx'

args = {}
if user_input == 'tgw-xxxx':
    args['TransitGateway'] = user_input
else:
    args['VpnGateway'] = user_input
```

Then you can "unpack" that dictionary into the function's arguments:

```
some_api_call(
    CustomerGatewayId='blah',
    BgpAsn=65000,
    **args
)
```

That will call `some_api_call(..., TransitGateway='something')` or `some_api_call(..., VpnGateway='other')` based on the values in `args`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of setting the variable in the two conditional branches, you could just call the API with different arguments in each branch:

```
if user_input == 'tgw-xxxx':
    some_api_call(
       CustomerGatewayId='blah',
       BgpAsn=65000,
       TransitGateway=user_input
    )
else:
    some_api_call(
       CustomerGatewayId='blah',
       BgpAsn=65000,
       VpnGateway=user_input,
    )
```

If you must make only a single call, put all the keyword arguments into a dictionary, setting a different gateway in the conditional:

```
params = {
   CustomerGatewayId='blah',
   BgpAsn=65000,
}

if user_input == 'tgw-xxxx':
    params['TransitGateway'] = user_input
else:
    params['VpnGateway'] = user_input
```

You can then pass all the parameters with the 'double splat' command:

```
some_api_call(**params)
```